# Time series regression with multiple independent variables

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression

it's been a while since i studied statistics and im a bit rusty on the topic but im looking for some advice on times series regression.

I'm trying to generate a time series regression model where i have one dependent variable(y) and several independent variables(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5); all the variables are in weekly data for 20 years. Ultimately im trying to find how much all the independent variables explain y(R squared) and the contribution for each independent variable. Also im trying to retrieve the same results(how much the independent variables explain y and each of their contribution) for each year. Would I have to use a VAR model? and which method would be effective explaining the contribution part?

Comment: Hi @johnnykim. A VAR would be the **incorrect** specification given that VARs are a system of endogenous equations with multiple dependent variables. Models with a single dependent variable are along the lines of 'distributed lag models' or 'autoregressive distributed lag' models, if you wish to lag your dependent variable.

Comment: What EB3112 said holds if the $x$s are truly independent variables. If they merely are right-hand-side variables in the equation for $y$ but in fact every variable affects each other with some time lag (or even simultaneously), a VAR could be a valid choice.